# How to change the server path and port of an ASP.NET Core site running in Visual Studio 2017 and IISEXPRESS

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and IIS Express to test and run  3  ASP.NET core Web application and Web API.

Currently, I am using 3 ports 81, 82 and 83 to run all the 3 application. The urls are like below:

```
http://localhost:81 
http://localhost:82 
http://localhost:83
```

How can I configure Visual Studio Web Project to use URL path, instead of port, so the URLs become like below, such that I can run and debug all the applications **simultaneously**:

```
http://localhost/App1/ 
http://localhost/App2/ 
http://localhost/App3/
```